# what is a socket? Is it a process?

Tags: sockets, networking, operating-system

I am studying os concepts and I found socket as the end point of communication. Now what exactly is a socket? Is it a process through means of which a system communicates?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket?

Comment: I have read. It says "Inter Process Communication Flow".Does this mean it is a process? If so how each process gets its IP?

Comment: Your question boils down to 'teach me about networking and sockets'.  It's WAY too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading the Wikipedia article, I can see why you may be confused.

A socket is a virtual device. That is, it is a device that is written in software and has no physical device. Thus, you can read to and write from a socket, like you would do to a terminal.

Sockets work in pairs to communicate and are usually bidirectional. One reads to socket (A) and writes to socket (B) --- or ---- writes to socket (A) and reads from socket --- or --- switches back and forth.

Generally sockets are used for network communications. They can usually support multiple protocols (TPC/IP, UDP/IP, even DECnet--the gamut depends upon the underlying system).

Sockets can be used for interprocess communication on a single system as well.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the c-family languages and their based languages implement socket as [Berkeley sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) which are implemented as [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). From Wikipedia:

> In the traditional implementation of Unix, file descriptors index into
>   a per-process file descriptor table maintained by the kernel, that in
>   turn indexes into a system-wide table of files opened by all
>   processes, called the file table. This table records the mode with
>   which the file (or other resource) has been opened: for reading,
>   writing, appending, and possibly other modes. It also indexes into a
>   third table called the inode table that describes the actual
>   underlying files.[3] To perform input or output, the process passes
>   the file descriptor to the kernel through a system call, and the
>   kernel will access the file on behalf of the process. The process does
>   not have direct access to the file or inode tables.

So on a high-level, sockets are implemented as files whose file-descriptors or handles are referenced as identifier to the socket.